# Creating a login page for iOS app: "View Controller“ is unreachable because it has no entry points, and no identifier for runtime access

Tags: ios, xcode

> "View Controller“ is unreachable because it has no entry points, and no identifier for runtime access via -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]

[image]

Why the circled part says exit instead of view controller and how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you try to right/ctrl drag from that symbol into your view controller by chance?  What are you trying to achieve with that view controller?

Comment: im trying to link the view to variables. please watch  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2hiaoaRBQ0&t=68s at 1:06.

Comment: Yeah that video doesn't make it very clear.  You need to right/ctrl drag from the actual control you want to link.  You appear to have dragged from the exit.  Clear that and just try again from the control you want to link.

Comment: thank you, will try and see if that works

Comment: You get this problem when you add a new view controller and fail to connect it with the existing view controller, for example the entry point view controller. Try to delete the existing connection between the view controllers and the ctrl+drag to connect the view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the controller as **Initial View Controller**. As Initial View controller would be not marked this error Would be coming. Select your view controller and do the steps:-

In **Attribute Inspector** You will find this

[image]

And After marking this option you will see this arrow on your view controller:-

[image]