# TableViewController's UItableView how to add to root view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hello i am new to objective C in iOS. I am trying to understand how UITableViewControllers work using the Main.storyboard.

I created on Main.storyboard a UIViewController and a UITableViewController. My UITableViewController consists of a UITableView, UITableViewCell and UIView. I added the code to populate with one row the UITableView which exists on UITableViewController. In my UIViewController .m i import "TableViewController.h" to create an instance of my UITableView from the UITableViewController and i use the following code to add it to the main UIViewController

```
 TableViewController *mytableview = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
 [mytableview.loaddatatable reloadData];
 [self.view addSubview:mytableview.loaddatatable];
```

When i run the app nothing happens, i get no errors. UITableView does not show up. I get this warning though

> “Table View Controller“ is unreachable because it has no entry points,
> and no identifier for runtime access via -[UIStoryboard
> instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]. [9]

Then i searched for this error in stackoverflow and came up with this [Creating a login page for iOS app: "View Controller“ is unreachable because it has no entry points, and no identifier for runtime access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253685/creating-a-login-page-for-ios-app-view-controller-is-unreachable-because-it-h)

The Initial View Controller option that is mentioned in the above link is crashing the app when i enabled it in my UITableViewController which is ok because i guess only one View Controller can be initialized at a time.

So i need to populate the UITableView datasource in UITableViewController .m and add it in the root UIViewController...how is this possible?

Comment: Hint: dataSource, delegate

Comment: I have added dataSource, delegate in TableViewController.h @interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> then implemented in TableViewController.m should i add them to TableViewController.m?

Comment: You seem to be a little confused on the fundamentals.  While you can embed one view controller in another via a container view, this isn't normally how you would start if you just needed a tableview.  Also, the way you are creating an instance of your tableview is via its initialiser rather than from the storyboard, so it won't have any connected outlets, registered cell or be connected to the data source/delegate.  If you just want a `UITableView` in your main view controller, just add a table view to that view controller.  No need for a `UTableViewController` at all.

Comment: Also, since you are just starting out, unless you are working for an organisation that uses Objective C, start with Swift.

Comment: I am confused for sure. I was thinking to have seperately the data of the UItableView from the main view controller. Thanks for your answer. Yes i need to use objective c no chance for Swift. So i just add an UITableView in my main view controller. So whats the point of UITableViewController and how can be used?

Comment: I never use `UITableViewController` if you ask me.  I would use `UITableView` with `UIViewController`, creating one through the storyboard if I were you.

Comment: So if i want to have seperate class of the UITableVIew that i am going to add through storyboard in my main view i just create a .h .m for that UITableView and assign the class through the UITableView? and what the .h .m should have as interface UIViewController?

Comment: It was a terrible hint.  I didn't read the question carefully.  I'm sorry about that.

Comment: If you are going to use `UIViewController` and write code in Objective-C, you need to create a property for the table guy in the h file and synthesize thing in the m file.  That's too much trouble.  That's why most people never go back to Objective-C after switching to Swift.

Comment: ok but i want to have a seperate class for the UITableView data...

Comment: As El Tomato, the UITableViewController probably isn't used that often.  If you need to have a view controller that is nothing but a tableview it is OK, but most view controllers have some other view.  You can use one in a container view, so that the containing view controller has the other elements, but that isn't beginner territory

Comment: @stefanosn You can (and should) have a separate class for your data model, but your view controller should implement your table view data source methods, accessing the data from the model as required

Comment: Oh only data model can be in a seperate class data source accessing the data of UITableView should be in main view controller?

Comment: Yes, if you try and put your data source methods in another class you will probably find that it isn't a good approach.  Sooner or later you will need to refer to your view controller and then you need to couple your view controller class and that class.

Comment: There is actually one advantage in using `UITableViewController`.  You can use static cells, which cannot be done through `UIViewController`.